# fopen: failed to open stream: No such file or directory - but file/directory exists

Tags: php, bash, error-handling, fopen, interactive-shell

**Edit: Originally I simplified the original csv file (from `com1_webscrapersolution_new_email-10-02-20.csv` to `products.csv`) to minimise/simplify the question, but it turned out the file name is of consequence here and is key to the solution.  I have edited the question in such a way to make this apparent.  I have also added an answer without an known explanation which I'm hoping someone else can provide.**

For the following problem, I can confirm that

- `/folder/custom_csv_parsing_functions.php` exists, the relevant excerpt is shown below
- <s>/c1/products.csv</s> /c1/com1_webscrapersolution_new_email-10-02-20.csv exists and may be viewed in full [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/huy1rflwsr0hl3t/products.csv?dl=0)

I am running the PHP in bash as `php -f file.php`.

`file.php`:

```
    <?php

    include('/folder/custom_csv_parsing_functions.php');

    $out = '/c1/com1_webscrapersolution_new_email-10-02-20.csv';


    //ENCLOSE HD DQUOTE

    $in = $out;

    $out = str_replace('.csv','_enc_hd.csv',$in);

    enclose_headers_dquote($in,$out);
```

throws the error:

> fopen('<s>/c1/products.csv</s>com1_webscrapersolution_new_email-10-02-20.csv'):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /folder/custom_csv_parsing_functions.php
>   on line 58

Excerpt from `/folder/custom_csv_parsing_functions.php`:

```
//removed code here as this is an excerpt

function enclose_headers_dquote($csv_input_file, $csv_output_file){

    $line = fgets(fopen($csv_input_file, 'r')); //this is line 58

    $line = str_replace("\r\n", '', $line);

    $arr = explode(',', $line);

    $header = '"' . implode('","', $arr) . '"';

    $header = array(
        $header
    );

    $fulltext = file_get_contents($csv_input_file);

    $fulltext = explode("\r\n", $fulltext);

    array_shift($fulltext);

    $reconstituted_csv_array = array_merge($header, $fulltext);
    $reconstituted_csv_str   = implode("\r\n", $reconstituted_csv_array);
    file_put_contents($csv_output_file, $reconstituted_csv_str);

}
```

If the file <s>products.csv</s>com1_webscrapersolution_new_email-10-02-20.csv exists, and is set to 777 permissions, why is PHP reporting "fopen('<s>/c1/products.csv</s>com1_webscrapersolution_new_email-10-02-20.csv'): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"?

Further, I can confirm that running the PHP directly in bash interactive shell does succeed:

```
[root@server c1]# php -a
Interactive shell

php > include('/folder/custom_csv_parsing_functions.php');
php > enclose_headers_dquote('/c1/com1_webscrapersolution_new_email-10-02-20.csv','/c1/com1_webscrapersolution_new_email-10-02-20_enc_hd.csv');
```

Successful output is `/c1/com1_webscrapersolution_new_email-10-02-20_enc_hd.csv` (can be viewed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/61z8mbbzw125nuy/products_enc_hd.csv?dl=0)).

So why doesn't it work when running the PHP in bash as `php -f file.php`?

Comment: `('../c1/products.csv')`

Comment: I think that you are repeating a mistake I am doing so many times. Please keep in mind that `/folder/custom_csv_parsing_functions.php` and `./folder/custom_csv_parsing_functions.php` are two completely different paths. In other words, try adding a single dot `.` at the beginning of the path

Comment: @PavelJanicek but in my case, `/folder/custom_csv_parsing_functions.php` is an absolute path.  That means `folder` dir is in the server root, so is your advice still applicable?

Comment: @user136649 it is not in that case. I instantly suspected it is NOT in document root and as said earlier, I was unable to spot this so many times, that I instantly assumed that you are hold by the same error

Comment: There is second thing. below you are calling function `enclose_headers_dquote` from `/c1` folder, but in your example, you are includung it from `/folder` folder. Are the two functions same? As in, I am assuming that root cause is still some hard to find typo in code

Comment: `enclose_headers_dquote` is a function inside `custom_csv_parsing_functions.php`, which resides in the absolute path `/folder`.  And yes, I am calling from another php file in `/c1` which includes() `/folder/custom_csv_parsing_functions.php`

Comment: @PavelJanicek if you are interested, check my answer.  Do you understand why it works when the file is actually renamed from `com1_webscrapersolution_new_email-10-02-20.csv` to `com1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand why but this works, and I will have to edit the original question accordingly.

Unfortunately, in trying to comply with minimal example I renamed the actual name of the csv file from `com1_webscrapersolution_new_email-10-02-20.csv` to `products.csv` in order to simplify the name, thinking this difference was of no consequence.

When I renamed to `com1.csv`, it worked.  I'm assuming it has to do with the complexity of all the character types in the name and the way it is parsed or some such.

I have no idea why this difference makes a difference?  Have I violated rules of file naming in Linux?  Both dashes, numbers and underscores are all legal in Linux file names, no?

I have even explicitly passed the name as `'\'c1/com1_webscrapersolution_new_email-10-02-20.csv\''` so the argument value provided would be explicitly enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: In your code above, you are having few "renaming" shenanigans with the file name. You have two approaches to follow. Either know "It works with `products.csv`, so the file name MUST be that and it works, so I am not touching it" or, you have to keep in mind that there is some **stupid** typo somewhere, so you split code to as many lines as possible to see where it is actually. My current guess is that you have mismatch between hyphen`-` and dash`–`

Comment: And just to add: Do not feel stupid doing this. If I had a cent for each of mistake of that type, I would be probably king of the world :)